# MySQL primary key query scans 5000x too many rows

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to run a simple SELECT query with the WHERE statement based on the PRIMARY KEY. I am running MySQL 5.7.9 on a GCE instance with 32 cores and 30 GB RAM. There are ~300M records in 500 partitions. 99.9999% of my queries are from the last 2 days, and that data fits entirely in memory, verified in that I am seeing ~0 bytes being read from the disk. My CPU is pegged consistently at 100% with 10-20 of these similar queries running concurrently.

I'm tracking some Google search data, so there are 100 `rank`s per combination of `Requested`, `IsPriority` and `KeywordID`. Despite my primary index being design so that no scans should be required, when I look at `EXPLAIN`, it shows that 552k rows are being scanned to return 100 rows.

On average, it is taking 20-40s to return 100 rows from RAM that are pointed directly to by a primary key. What can I do to speed up this query?

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT * FROM data.Rankings
    -> WHERE Requested = '2016-02-26 00:00:00' AND NOT IsPriority AND KeywordID = '7387777811691965572'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: Rankings
   partitions: p20160226
         type: ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: const
         rows: 552598
     filtered: 1.00
        Extra: Using where
1 row in set, 2 warnings (0.01 sec)
```

Here's the DB table

```
CREATE TABLE `Rankings` (
  `KeywordID` char(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Requested` timestamp NOT NULL,
  `IsPriority` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `Retrieved` timestamp NOT NULL,
  `Rank` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `Source` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `ExternalID` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Phrase` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  // another 40 data columns of varying types
  PRIMARY KEY (`Requested`,`IsPriority`,`KeywordID`,`Rank`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED
// I have about 500 daily partitions over the last 1.5 years
/*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Requested))
(PARTITION p20160222 VALUES LESS THAN (1456185600) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160223 VALUES LESS THAN (1456272000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160224 VALUES LESS THAN (1456358400) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160225 VALUES LESS THAN (1456444800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160226 VALUES LESS THAN (1456531200) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160227 VALUES LESS THAN (1456617600) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160228 VALUES LESS THAN (1456704000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20160229 VALUES LESS THAN (1456790400) ENGINE = InnoDB) */;
```

Comment: I would have to look more carefully to provide a solid answer.  I usually avoid compound keys in indexes -- the query optimizer has to do a lot of work to figure out whether it can use the PK as an index.  Instead, consider creating multiple indexes on each of the fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect that the `NOT` is causing problems.  How about using an equality comparison?

```
SELECT *
FROM data.Rankings
WHERE Requested = '2016-02-26 00:00:00' AND 
      IsPriority = 0 AND
      KeywordID = '7387777811691965572';
```

Comment: That fixed the problem immediately! That's crazy! I'll mark this as accepted in 3 minutes when SO lets me. I'd appreciate any insight into why that makes such a huge difference in execution time while still returning the same results.

Comment: @DerekPerkins . . . I think the answer is that the optimizer would first have to recognize the equivalence of  `NOT IsPriority` and `IsPriority = 0` for numeric types and then apply this information.  The construct is probably too rare (and easily worked around) for this to be on the designers' radar.

Comment: Makes sense I guess. I'll certainly be more wary of NOT in the future. :)